# eclipse cdt auto include <iostream>

Tags: c++11, gcc, autocomplete, include, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse for Java, library classes are auto-imported in the class file
and it also prompts to choose which library if 2 library classes have the same method .
Is there a similar option for Eclipse CDT to automatically include iostream, math.h, stdio.h. Or do I need to type it out for every source file.
My compiler is Linux GCC.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse CDT does have the option to automatically add and managed the `#include`s for you.

To do so, select *Source* menu -> *Organize Includes*, or if you prefer the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (letter o).

The settings that control what the organize includes does is controlled from preferences -> *C/C++* -> *Code Style* -> *Organize Includes*, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

If you have a symbol that is in multiple include files, you will be prompted. In this screenshot I have `b` with no `#include` already covering it, and two includes in my project that define the symbol (works with system includes too):

[image]

Comment: `int main() {printf("ff");return 0;}` eclipse shows no error on save . shows error"not declared in scope " on build all. i have default preferences in Organize Includes

Comment: Doing Ctrl-Shift-O did nothing presumably? I can't reproduce that problem here, if you can create reproducible failure, please file a bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT

Comment: Yeah, but `Ctrl-Shift-O` adds function header `int printf(const char *__format);` not `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: I have tried it a few different ways and can't reproduce, please file a bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT listing the exact setup (OS version, compiler version, Eclipse CDT version)